# How can I debug problems importing GeoTiffs?

Tags: import, geography, geographics

I have not been able to import DEM GeoTiffs with Mathematica.

I downloaded two different DEM files in a GeoTIFF format from Earth Explorer (https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), one from the Aster data set and one from the SRTM data set and tried to import them. In both cases Mathematica completed the import with no error and shows a reasonable GeoTiff summary, but the plot it shows is just a plain gray square:

[image]

One possibility is that the gray levels are not balanced correctly, but I have no idea how to detect and fix this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with some GeoTIFF files. My solution was to import them into some GIS software (e.g. QGIS) and then export them as a new GeoTIFF file. This exported new file I could then import into Mathematica without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "Image" option in Import:

```
input = Import[pathAster, {"GeoTIFF","Image"}]
```