# How to find the spatial coordinate in a Geotiff that is not recognized by Mathematica as Geotiff

Tags: image-processing, import

I am trying to read a geotiff file that is not recognized by Mathematica as a geotiff file.

```
Import["NOAA.tif", "Elements"]

{"Animation", "Author", "BitDepth", "CameraTopOrientation", 
"Channels", "ColorMap", "ColorProfileData", "ColorSpace", "Comments", 
"CopyrightNotice", "Data", "DateTime", "Device", 
"DeviceManufacturer", "Exif", "FlashUsed", "GeoPosition", 
"GPSDateTime", "Graphics", "GraphicsList", "Image", "Image3D", 
"ImageCount", "ImageCreationDate", "ImageEncoding", "ImageList",
"ImageResolution", "ImageSize", "IPTC", "MakerNote", 
"MetaInformation", "RawData", "RawExif", "RawIPTC", "RawXMP",
"RedEyeCorrection", "RowsPerStrip", "Summary", "SummarySlideView", 
"Thumbnail", "ThumbnailList", "TileSize", "XMP"}
```

I can read the elevation from "Data", however, I have no clue where is the spatial coordinate range in this file.
Any help is appreciated.

The file is 1.4 GB and can be accessed through
https://smttt-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/personal/w10134554_usm_edu/Documents/NOAA.tif?csf=1&web=1&e=qSzHXh

Comment: How big is this tif file? What is its location?

Comment: Can you do `Import["NOAA.tif", {"GeoTIFF", "Elements"}]` and see if that comes out?

Comment: A file with this name is not present on my machine. @CarlLange

Comment: @Syed I meant for the OP to do it, as they haven't supplied the file :)

Comment: The file is 1.5 GB.
{"BitDepth", "Centering", "CentralScaleFactor", "Channels", \
"ColorSpace", "CoordinateSystem", "CoordinateSystemInformation", \
"Data", "DataFormat", "Datum", "ElevationRange", "Graphics", \
"GridOrigin", "Image", "InverseFlattening", "LinearUnits", \
"Projection", "ProjectionName", "RasterSize", "ReferenceModel", \
"SemimajorAxis", "SemiminorAxis", "SpatialRange", \
"SpatialResolution", "StandardParallels", "Summary"}

Comment: The Import["NOAA.tif", {"GeoTIFF", "Elements"}] return the above output but doesn't read the Spatial Range and returns Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as GeoTIFF format.

Comment: Related? [133032](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133032/27951). There seem to be quite a few problems importing GeoTIFF correctly in MMA.

Comment: Are you sure it's a GeoTIFF - if you put it into (for instance) QGIS, does it work correctly? Does it come with a second file that might contain the metadata?

Comment: As a contrasting example, I nearly always use Mathematica to look at GeoTIFFs - although the support for it is definitely a little lacking.

Comment: It is a GeoTiff, if I MatrixPlot the "Data" it clearly shows the bathymetry. I am just missing the coordinates.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to download from your link. As for being able to `MatrixPlot` the data, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's a GeoTIFF, since you can do that with regular TIFFs as well. I would strongly recommend you see whether the tiff works within QGIS, or use something like GDAL's `gdalinfo` to get the range.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me. I solved the issue by reading the original file with QGIS and exporting it as a GeoTiff.

Comment: @MahdiRazaz Glad to help!